Eventarc gcloud command returns error when specifying existing topic to use
i am creating an eventarc with gcloud and have existing topic i want to use (instead of eventarc creating new one and manage automatically)
the trigger will invoke a workflow when new files upload to a bucket.
my command
gcloud eventarc triggers create abc-trigger \
--location=asia \ #bucket location in asia
--destination-workflow=abc-workflow \
--destination-workflow-location=asia-southeast1 \
--event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--event-filters="bucket=input-bucket" \
--service-account=abc@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--transport-topic=projects/projectid/topics/existing-topic

error i got
(gcloud.eventarc.triggers.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request was invalid: trigger.transport.pubsub.topic is read-only except for Pubsub triggers and GCFv1 triggers
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - field: trigger.transport.pubsub.topic
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo
  requestId: 6c91d3c53c2f8bd5

i saw that it's supported in terraform  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8711 but why i am getting error?

Hi @unacorn, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
